# FFMPEG results in a black video from converting images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am attempting to create an mp4 video from a sequence of images numbered 1 to 100. The problem is that I keep on getting an output video that is black. Each images is as such

[image]

all the way to 100. The FFMPEG command that I have used is as follows

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i img%04d.png -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

The output from this command is as follows,

```
ffmpeg version N-69608-g9dc45d1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc  
4.9.2 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-        
bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --
enable-libbluray --enab
le-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc 
--enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --   
enable-libopenjp
eg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex 
--enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable
-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 
--enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5.  9.103 /  5.  9.103
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'img%04d.png':
Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 480x320, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] 264 - core 144 r2525 40bb568 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 
2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0    
analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=
7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0   
deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 
nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1   
open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf  
mbtree=1 crf=23.0
qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x320, q=-1--1, 30 fps,    
15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.21.102 libx264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  100 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       5kB time=00:00:03.26 bitrate=  11.4kbits/s
video:3kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 77.850037%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] frame I:1     Avg QP:10.00  size:    77
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] frame P:25    Avg QP:10.28  size:    25
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] frame B:74    Avg QP:13.68  size:    17
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  0.0%  3.0% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%     
0.0%    skip:100.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct:   
0.0%  skip:100.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] 8x8 transform intra:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 95%  0%  5%  0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049238a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
```

All of the 100 images are numbered "0001.png" to "0100.png". I created the images using java code.
I used ffplay to play the 3s long output video and this is what it looks like:

[image]

I have looked at other related questions posted here, but none of the suggestions have solved the problem. This is my first time using FFMPEG, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a link to the input files and a link to the output file.

Comment: What happens if the numbers are white - might be the background of the video is also black so you can't see them - just a guess though as only slightly familiar with FFMPEG, otherwise if can specify background to be white might be worth a try

Comment: What if you use straight command line?  Also use ffprobe show packeys to see if the output had any frames at all...